Looking for a Specific Collaboration Tools
I am wondering if there are any recommended collaborative modelling tools out there (like Figma or Miro), which can check a certain objects through all the files in the groups' repository.
For example, my team has 3 files, let's say file 1,2, and 3.
The objects in each files are as follows:
File 1 = A, A, B, B, C.
File 2 = A, B, C, D.
File 3 = B, C, C, D.
If we check/search for object A, the desired result is highlighting/informing me the location of all A(s), or where all A(s) are used, or anything similar in nature. In this case, the desired result should refers to 2 A(s) in File 1, and one A in File 2.
The tools that I have tried so far can only check/search within each files. Like, if we check/search for object A(s) in File 1, it only shows the 2 A(s) in File 1.
Thanks before.
